# How can I change the font-family of a div in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a general font-rule

```
* {
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and i want to change it for a single div

```
<div id="login-modal" class="active">
    <div id="login-form">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form id="login">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" required>

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" required>

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div> Rest of my code </div>
```

Changing it like this doesn't do anything

```
#login-modal {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I tried it for every single element and that worked.

```
#login-modal h2,
#login-modal label,
#login-modal input,
#login-modal button {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

But I dont understand why. Since I am new to Frontend, I would love to enhance my understanding of css

Comment: check devtools, it will show what css rules take effect and which ones don't

Comment: The question that this was marked a duplicate of does have the answer to your question as well as my answer below. You generally don't want to set inheritable properties (color, background, font) on all elements with the star selector

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```css
* {font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;}
```

This doesn't do what you want. What this means is that every single element has the font family `Permanent Marker`. What you should do instead is this:

```css
:root { font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive; }
* {font-family: inherit }
```

Comment: The question is why doesn't `#login-modal {font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}` override the Universal selector?

Comment: It does override the universal selector. The problem is that it isn't getting applied to children elements which is why he mentioned that he had to put the style on "every  single element". His question was why he had to put it on "every single element"